# Issue with order of Dygraphs callback

Tags: javascript, canvas, callback, dygraphs, operator-precedence

I have adjusted dygraphs a bit to help with page load times for dygraphs with a large amount of points to draw. To do this I have added a few lines of code to the drawPointsOnLine function around line 1378 of dygraph-combined.js. Instead of just increasing the counter by one (idx++):

```
if (pointsOnLine.length > 10000){
    window.scalingfactor = Math.round(pointsOnLine.length/10000);
    idx=idx+window.scalingfactor;
    window.scalingfactorset=true;
 } else{
    idx++;
    window.scalingfactor="";
    window.scalingfactorset=true;
 }
```

This code seems to be working perfectly for skipping a certain number of points to draw and updates as the dygraph is zoomed, panned and reverted.

The problem I have is with trying to display on the canvas how many points are being skipped. I decided to let the user know how many points are being skipped.
To do this I added in the underlayCallback where the canvas is drawn

```
if (scalingfactorset) {
    scalingfactormsg= "Every "+scalingfactor+" point(s) plotted";
    wid=canvas.measureText(scalingfactormsg);
    canvas.fillText(scalingfactormsg,area.x+area.w-wid.width-5,area.y+area.h-70);
} else {
    if ((<?php echo $lines; ?> -1) >10000) {
        firstscalingfactor=Math.round((<?php echo $lines; ?> -1)/10000);
        firstscalingfactormsg= "Every "+firstscalingfactor+" point(s) plotted";
        wid=canvas.measureText(firstscalingfactormsg);
        canvas.fillText(firstscalingfactormsg,area.x+area.w-wid.width-5,area.y+area.h-70);
    } else {
        firstscalingfactor="";
        firstscalingfactormsg= "Every "+firstscalingfactor+" point(s) plotted";
        wid=canvas.measureText(firstscalingfactormsg);
        canvas.fillText(firstscalingfactormsg,area.x+area.w-wid.width-5,area.y+area.h-70);
    }
```

However since I believe that underlaycallback function is called before points are drawn the scalingfactor will never be drawn as the correct value but the data will be scaled correctly.

At least that is what I would expect, but for some odd reason this will work perfectly as planned for some datsets when zooming panning and reverting to original view the canvas message will update with the correct scaling factor.

For other datasets on the first load it will be correct (I tried to hard code in a first scaling factor to fix this before I found out the supposed order of callbacks) but when you zoom, pan, or return to original view the scalingfator will be stuck to the empty string and display "Every point(s) plotted" even though the data is being scaled by a certain amount.

It seems to work more often for larger datasets than small datasets but there are a few small datasets that still work. I think this might have to do with the way dygraphs handles callbacks. I think if I could force dygraphs to draw the points first everything would be fixed but im not sure if it is possible.

If anyone knows anyway to fix this strange behavior please let me know. In case it matters I set scalingfactorset to false right before I call the dygraph, and the data are in csv format. I have also made sure there are no formatting errors between datasets when the code works and when it does not. Let me know if there is any other helpful info I can provide.

Comment: Maybe try [`drawCallback`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#drawCallback) instead of `underlayCallback`. As its name implies, underlayCallback draws _under_ the chart, i.e. before.

Comment: Also be aware that skipping large numbers of points will have undesirable effects, for example omitting minima and maxima, and completely distorting the plot when the data isn't evenly spaced.

Comment: I moved the message from the underlayCallback canvas to update a message below the dygraph using innerHTML in the drawCallback. The message displayed is exhibiting the exact same behavior as when the statement was in underlayCallback. I also aded in a statement to see what pointsOnLine.length was returning and noticed for the data where it breaks pointsOnLine.length is 0 for some reason. Is there another place where dygraphs keeps track of the number of points it is plotting?